# Non-DX VS Code Debugger

Tags: apex-debugger

Anyone know of a working debugger extension for VS Code that works for non-DX projects?  Or maybe how to setup the official SF debugger extension for a non-DX project (their wiki mentions it can be used for both sandboxes and scratch orgs)?

[Salesforce Debugger Wiki](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Apex-Debugger):

> Apex Debugger allows customers to debug their Apex code on sandbox instances (including in scratch orgs), in real time

I've read that they're dropping support for the Eclipse plugin and the Eclipses based IDE 2 so I've completely migrated to VS Code.  I've used the official SF Debugger Extension on a DX project and it works great.  But I also have times when I need to track down a bug and setting up a DX project would take longer than to just running through the affected classes.

Currently I use the ForceCode extension (which is also no longer being developed) to pull down and deploy code fixes.  I've read somewhere that the MavensMate extension (also no longer being developed) supports non-live debugging by reading through a debug log, but I can't get MavensMate to work from within our proxy.

Comment: Please see if @andrew-fawcett blog post can be helpful [Streaming Debug Logs to your console](https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/03/14/streaming-apex-logs-to-your-console/)

Comment: that was interesting, I didn't know we can do that.  the color, grep, and pipe would definitely make reading logs easier   But, this still isn't an alternative to live debugging.  For example, I won't be able to put in break points, examine variable values, step through code, etc..

Comment: Due to the SF architecture, it's impossible to have a real-time debugger. The closest thing is [Apex Retrospective Debugger available in The Welkin Suite](https://welkinsuite.com/features/debugging/apex-retrospective-debugger/)

Comment: @o-lexi they do have a debugger, and it worked well in [Eclipse for Non-DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_overview.htm) as well as in [VS Code if using DX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-apex-debugger).  I've used both and they were good.  But what I'm looking for is to setup for VS Code for Non-DX projects.

Comment: FYI for future readers.. Apex Debugging is now working with non-DX projects in VSCode. I just tried.

Comment: @javanoob can you share steps? When I try to run the Turn on Apex debugger log for Replay Debugger, I got below error:
["All --json output, including on error, is moving to stdout. Use the SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT environment variable to move over to the new functionality. This will become the default in version 45."]

is it because of the API version? My current project is on version 44

Comment: @LMudiyanse I am using `salesforcedx 45.0.9 (pre-release)` and my sandbox is on Spring'19.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of which extensions you are using, as long as you have the cli installed, and you just want to emit your debug statements, this will work in VS Code, go to the terminal window and enter this command:

```
sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color | grep USER_DEBUG
```

Then run your tests.  The debug messages will show up in the Terminal window.  This will not give you breakpoints etc. of course.

Also be aware, you can work on non-DX orgs but still have your code in DX format, which will allow you to use the native debugging within VSCode (assuming you have the Salesforce Extensions Pack, which you should).  The CLI has a converter, and so in your source control / local workspace, the code can be in the DX structure, but when you save/publish to the org, the cli automatically converts it back to the MDAPI format.

To convert to DX format use: `sfdx force:mdapi:convert`

Answer (score -2):

Use [Apex Replay Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-apex-replay-debugger):

> Why: Apex Debugger, our interactive debugger, debugs only sandboxes and scratch orgs. But you can use Apex Replay Debugger in any org that you have source code and a debug log for, including your production org. Apex Replay Debugger is not only free, it's open source!

VSCode has plugins and supports node modules which provide the following features:

- Code Retrieval and Deployment<sup>[1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=coveo.vsforce)</sup>
- VisualForce Linting<sup>[2](https://github.com/forcedotcom/eslint-plugin-visualforce)</sup>
- Apex Linting<sup>[3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apexlint)</sup>
- Static Analysis<sup>[4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.apex-pmd)</sup>
- Command line Testing<sup>[5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsforce)</sup>

**References**

- [Debug Node.js Apps using Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)
- [Running Node.js on WSL from Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/27/running-node-js-on-wsl-from-visual-studio-code/)
- [Integrating Prettier + ESLint + Airbnb Style Guide in VSCode](https://blog.echobind.com/integrating-prettier-eslint-airbnb-style-guide-in-vscode-47f07b5d7d6a?gi=ecf854af0f83)
- [Integrated Terminal in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)
- [VSCode ESLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- [eslint-plugin-visualforce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/eslint-plugin-visualforce)

Comment: A linter is not the same thing as a debugger - can you clarify how these resources support OP's objective?